# Swap capslock and control in virtual consoles

Tags: 10.04, keyboard, capslock, virtual-console

I'm using System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layout > Options > Ctrl key position > Swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, which works great for X.

How can I get the same for virtual consoles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set your preferred keyboard options: System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts > Options
2. Apply the layout and options system-wide: System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts > Apply System-Wide
3. Reboot for the changes to take effect in the virtual consoles.

To double-check that the settings have been applied, look for `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"` in `/etc/default/console-setup`. (Alternatively, if you know what you're doing you can go ahead and just edit this file directly.)

Comment: This does work, but I am looking for a way to affect only the virtual consoles instead of also all the accounts on the system when using X.  (I only have a handful here, so I just reset them after this.)

Comment: I see (since /etc/ is an hg repo using etckeeper) this modifies /etc/default/console-setup and /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz.  If I was to modify the former myself, what command generates the latter cached.kmap.gz?

Comment: Actually, I put that in a [separate question](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/how-does-etc-defaut-console-setup-work).

Comment: why is this wrong answer still up? The OP asked about virtual consoles, not about terminals in X.

Comment: @JayEye Can you be more precise about what's wrong with it? As far as I know it does (or did seven years ago) impart the desired change in both X terminal emulators and virtual consoles.

Comment: XKBOPTIONS, like the name says, is about the X keyboard. It has no place in /etc/default/console-setup, and indeed it does not appear in the man page for console-setup.

Comment: @JayEye In 10.04 `/etc/default/console-setup` contains `XKBOPTIONS` by default and includes an explanation that it "can have the same values as [...] in /etc/X11/xorg.conf". https://paste.ubuntu.com/24381625/