# How does /etc/default/console-setup work?

Tags: 10.04, virtual-console

Following up on [modifying virtual consoles' keymaps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4405/swap-capslock-and-control-in-virtual-consoles), how can I edit /etc/default/console-setup?

Will the file be parsed on each boot (then cached in /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz), or do I need to run a certain command after every manual change?

The description for package [console-setup](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/console-setup) does give its basic purpose, but am I missing documentation on how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setupcon is the program which is responsible for updating /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz.
setupcon is run on startup inside the initramfs image, so you'll need to update that before the changes apply

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, /etc/default/console-setup is checked each boot (or read from the cached file), but what I see in my FS isn't what is seen by setupcon when the initramfs image is still being used?

Comment: Actually, I think it's the opposite, console-setup requires an initramfs update but the cached keymap is always read. You need to test to verify :-)

Answer (score 3):

The program setupcon uses the /etc/default/console-setup file. Setupcon has a man page that refers to a README file. The README file is /usr/share/doc/console-setup/README.gz. That file indicates that you need to invoke setupcon as part of the boot sequence to have the console parameters changed automatically.

Edit the /etc/default/console-setup file to suit your needs. You can verify that the settings do what you want by opening a terminal `ctrl-alt-f1`, logging in and running `setupcon`.

To make the changes happen automatically with each reboot, edit the file /etc/rc.local to add the line `setupcon` above the `exit 0` line.

Both files, /etc/default/console-setup and /etc/rc.local require root privileges to edit.

Comment: So, does this happen automatically with "stock" Ubuntu 10.04?  Does the console-setup package do it?  How do I check?

Comment: I don't think it is automatic. Try adding /bin/setupcon to the startup applications (system/preferences/startup applictions).

Comment: That seems the wrong place, as it would run after logging into X rather than at boot time.

Comment: Right, I edited my answer to correct.